# light weight alternative to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a situation for each i am trying to find a better (read optimized) pattern to employ.
Essentially, i have three activities - `LaunchActivity`, `WelcomeActivity` and `MainActivity`.
The `LaunchActivity` is the `DEFAULT` `LAUNCHER` activity and in my case, `LaunchActivity` does not show any UI i.e i don't call `setContentView()` at all in `onCreate()`. All that i am doing is, essentially, in `onStart()`, i check certain conditions and based on the result, either launch `WelcomeActivity` or `MainActivity`.

Now, i am wondering, should i really use an `Activity` [`LaunchActivity`'s superclass] do some checks? Is there a light weight option that i could use to quicken the launch process since instantiating an `Activity` could be fairly time consuming and expensive?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I use activity acting as a splash screen in my applications while dealing with such kind of scenarios.The benefit of doing this is that it is giving my application a nice interface, and a graphically rich promotion, and also in that splash Activity,I am taking decisions that what activity should be started next on the basis of last saved state of my Android Application.
[image]

---

Another alternative(which i will not implement in any application developed by me) is to start the Welcome Activity everytime,and in its `onCreate()` Check some condition.If that condition is met then, open the MainActivity by using intents...else carry on with the flow of the welcome Activity

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(your condition)//check some condtion here
    {
      // if met,go to MainActivity
    }
    else
    {
       //carry on with the flow of WelcomeActivity
    }
  }
}
```

**Overall, I believe using the first approach is better way , because it is just adding an overhead of only one activity,but making the flow of the application cleaner**

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with nice graph. To me, the LaunchActivity is in essence your SplashActivity. Speed is important to me while launching rather than rich UI for splash. I am using an Activity for just making one if-else call in LaunchActivity. Trying to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Then just go with the other approach... :)